# Permutations of a list python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I need to define a function apply(L, P) where L is a list and P is a permutation, and it should return the list L o P. Assume `len(L) = len(P)`

What I've got so far is

```
import itertools 
def apply(L, P):
    for perm in L:
        return perm
```

An example of input is `apply(['ah', 'boo', 'cc', 'du', 'eh'], [1, 4, 3, 2, 0])`
But the only output from that is `'ah'`

Any help would be great.

Comment: And you're not actually using P anywhere.

Comment: `return` will immediately end the function and return the value as the only return value. So you are essentially stopping your loop there. You might want to make it a generator instead and use `yield`.

Comment: @poke I'm fairly sure that she/he wants to return the entire list. But this also made me think of yield/generators :p. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/645270) a good read on the subject if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a task most easily achieved with a list comprehension:

```
>>> def apply(L, P):
...   return [ L[i] for i in P ]
... 
>>> apply(['ah', 'boo', 'cc', 'du', 'eh'], [1, 4, 3, 2, 0])
['boo', 'eh', 'du', 'cc', 'ah']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version:

```
def apply(L, P):
    newL = [None]*len(L)
    for i,index in enumerate(P):
        newL[i] = L[index]
    return newL
```

This can easily be accomplished in one line in python, but I wanted to illustrate what's happening here.

The entire list is created before returning. `return` means that the function should exit and *return* the specified value. In your case that is `'ah'` since it's the first element in the list you're looping through.

If you want to learn python, check out svk's very pythonic list comprehension.